# Is there a way to add new items to the context menu of taskbar icons in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, context-menu, file-shortcut

It is possible to add custom items to the context menu of specific file types through the registry, however extending the .lnk files, that I suppose are used in the windows 10 taskbar has no effect on the context menu that accessible from the taskbar, only on the ones accessible from desktop or file explorers.

I'd like to either add a custom option to the jumplist menu (on the taskbar), or to the menu that shows up once right-clicking the shortuct icon in the jumplist menu.

My goal is to be able to open the file location of items located on the taskbar more efficiently, currently the best way I know is:

1. Right click the icon on the taskbar
2. Right click the app's shortcut in the jumplist menu
3. Click on 'Properties'
4. Click on 'Open file location'
5. Close the Properties window

I'd like to shave off as many steps as possible from this process.